# Optimize nested loop to create HTML elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, optimization

I'm developing an onscreen keyboard using HTML / Javascript. The keyboard is generated at runtime.

I'm using a JSON datastructure to store the different keyboard layouts, language settings etc.

```
var initParams = {
    keyboardLanguage: "de",
    keyboardLayout: {
        de: {
            row1: ["Q","W","E","R","T","Z","U","I","O","P"],
            row2: ["A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L"],
            row3: ["Y","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
        },
        en: {
            row1: ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P"],
            row2: ["A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L"],
            row3: ["Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
        }       
    }
}
```

And here is the function that does the job:

```
function CreateKeyHtmlElements(){

    var divElement = document.createElement("div");

    for(var obj in initParams.keyboardLayout[initParams.keyboardLanguage]){

        var keyRow = divElement.cloneNode(false);
        keyRow.id = "key" + obj;
        keyRow.className = "keyboard-key-row";

        for(var i = 0, l = initParams.keyboardLayout[initParams.keyboardLanguage][obj].length; i < l; i +=1){

            var key = divElement.cloneNode(false);
            key.id = "key-" + initParams.keyboardLayout[initParams.keyboardLanguage][obj][i];
            key.className = "keyboard-key";

            key.textContent = initParams.keyboardLayout[initParams.keyboardLanguage][obj][i];

            keyRow.appendChild(key);

            $(key).appendTo(keyRow);

        }

        $(keyRow).appendTo($("#keyboard-key-box"));

    }

}
```

Are there any effective ways to optimize this function, particularly the loops, using jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a special HTML element for aggregation of html, not to make actual dom manipulations

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

But as long as the benchmarks don't show actual difference between the fragment approach and inserting sting via innerHTML ([proof](http://jsperf.com/another-documentfragment-vs-string-concat-innerhtml-tes))
You can do something like this:

```
var result = '<div class="keyboard">';    
$(initParams.keyboardLayout[initParams.keyboardLanguage]).each(function(i,obj){
       result += '<div class="row">';
       result += '<div class="key">'+obj.join('</div class="key"><div>')+'</div>';
       result += '</div>';
    })
$(".target").append(result);
```

This doesn't give you a chance to add ID's but that actually dosn't matter, just when binding use `$(el).index()` to get the column index and `$(el).parent().index()` to get row